Erroneous .tar.gz created by drush archive:dump. The archive cannot be restored with drush archive:restore
I use Debian 11, PHP 8.1.28, drupal/core-recommended:10.2.6 and drush/drush:12.5.2.
When I run drush archive:dump no error is reported. But when I want to restore the archive with drush archive:restore I receive the following error that seems to be related to the contents of the .tar.gz file:
[warning] PharData::extractTo(/home/drupal/drush-backups/drushTpUnvd/drupal_site/code/web/.gitignore): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory ArchiveRestoreCommands.php:258

In ArchiveRestoreCommands.php line 258:

  Extraction from phar "/home/drupal/drush-backups/drupal_site.tar.gz" failed: Cannot extract "code/web/.gitignore", could not open for writing "/home/drupal/drush-backups/drushTpUnvd/drupal_site/code/web/.gitignore"

The command "tar -xvzf drupal_site.tar.gz" reports errors similar with the following at the standard error:
tar: code/web/.gitignore: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/modules/README.txt: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/robots.txt: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/.eslintrc.json: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/.csslintrc: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/profiles/README.txt: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/.ht.router.php: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/INSTALL.txt: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/autoload.php: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/README.md: Cannot open: Not a directory
...
tar: code/web/sites/default/settings.php: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/sites/default/services.yml: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: code/web/sites/default/default.services.yml: Cannot open: Not a directory
...
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Is this a known issue? Is there any workaround?
Thank you.

I answer the question because I've identified the problem and a workaround:
The problem is cause by symbolic links. My project root folder (the one containing the file composer.json) was structured as follows:
mysite                      # project root folder
   |
   +---- composer.json
   |
   +---- vendor             # folder
   |
   +---- docroot            # folder
   |        |
   |        +---- xdata     # symlink to ../web
   |
   +---- web                # folder (webroot)

drush archive:restore is able to create an archive for this directory structure but the archive it creates cannot be restored with drush archive:restore or deflated with tar -xvzf. The problem is caused by the symbolic link that makes the folder ../web to be stored inside the archive as a file. So when it is deflated, there is no folder named web in which to store the files that would go there.
I would add that a website tree can contain symlinks and be correctly archived with drush archive:dumpe as long as the symbolic links are not in those folders saved by drush (for example the ./vendor folder contains symlinks but it is skipped by drush).
